# FromFile is not a member of "iTextSharp.text.Image"

Tags: vb.net

I want to set a background image of windows form using code. and I am doing so using this code. Code in the form's page load event:

```
Me.Panel2.BackgroundImage = Image.FromFile(My.Settings.BGimage.ToString)
```

and code of button's click event.

```
Dim BGimage As Object
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnselect.Click
        If OpenFileDialog1.ShowDialog() = DialogResult.OK Then
            BGimage = OpenFileDialog1.FileName.ToString
            TextBox1.Text = OpenFileDialog1.FileName.ToString
        End If
End Sub
Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnset.Click
        Me.Panel1.BackgroundImage = Image.FromFile(OpenFileDialog1.FileName)
        My.Settings.BGimage = BGimage
        Wait.Show()
End Sub
```

But there are more another namespaces in the form and these are,

```
Imports iTextSharp
Imports iTextSharp.text
Imports iTextSharp.text.pdf
```

So, I am facing error in the page load event code, and error is "FromFile is not a member of 'iTextSharp.text.Image' "

I am getting a blue squiggly line under "Image.FromFile" in the page load event code. and as compile error.
So, I stuck here. I can't understand what to do.

Comment: Namespace clash. Use `System.Drawing.Image.FromFile`. Try searching.

Comment: Yeah, it's works...thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add appropriate namespace, like this:

```
Me.Panel2.BackgroundImage = System.Drawing.Image.FromFile(My.Settings.BGimage.ToString)
```